# mercurial to sync to flashdrive and multiple machines

Tags: windows, linux, mercurial

Let me first describe what I'd like to do, and why I want to do it, and then let me tell you what I tried and the problems I've had.

I have multiple machines I want to keep in sync using a usb flashdrive. There's my home laptop, my travelling laptop, and my office desktop. And all have a dual windows7-kubuntu11.10 setup. I'm the only user, I'm not connected to any network. My only worry is having the latest files in the machine I use at any given time. I'm very good about sync-ing to the usb flashdrive every time I connect to a machine and every time I disconnect. I rarely forget. With my setup I have as many as 7 copies of my stuff, 3 on linux, 3 on widows, and 1 on the usb (not to mention backups, many of those).

I'm new to this, so at this point in time I have no system to go back and forth between windows and linux. I have been using syncback on windows and dirsyncpro on linux, but to set the scene consider that I'm too thick to understand how to use rsync. I am learning to use mercurial precisely because I understand it can work across platforms.

I have set up mercurial on my linux machines (not tried on windows yet), I have 1) set up an email in the .hgrc and used the very same file on all machines, 2) I have done $hg init followed by $hg add and $hg commit -m "first commit" in all the folders I want to track, 3) I have done $hg clone /home/docs /media/USBNAME/docs and have verified that a clone did indeed get copied onto the usb flashdrive, 4) I have tested that adding files and doing $hg push /media/USBNAME/docs does copy the new file into the clone directory onto the usb flashdrive, but 5) I created a new directory with some new files and that won't get pushed. This is pretty much where I'm stuck.

```
$hg addremove
$hg commit -m "added stuff"
$ hg push /media/USBNAME/docs
pushing to /media/USBNAME/docs
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote head bb0e20a00aa3!
(you should pull and merge or use push -f to force)
```

I felt at the time that forcing the push may have been a little, well, forceful. So I did a pull instead. But this deleted the new folders. I was able to get them back by doing $hg rollback, $hg rervert newfolder/newfile, but that was both scary and tedious. And now I'm back to square one, how can I push these new files and the new directory onto the usb flashdrive?

At a general and basic level, here are my 2 questions: how can I handle directory additions and deletions? I will typically use a file manager like krusader, dolphin or gnome-commander, on linux, to add and remove files. Mercurial has no problem seeing the new files in the new folders and committing them. But I can't get it to push them onto the "clone." This problem is only for a new folder, as far as I can tell. Adding new files to existing folders works as expected.

EDIT #1

Following Martin's suggestions, I would like to report back and seek some follow-up advice on what I'm doing.

```
$ cd /home/docs
$ hg status
$ hg addremove
$ hg commit -m "yet another test"
$ hg push /media/USBNAME/docs
  pushing to /media/USBNAME/docs
  searching for changes
  abort: push creates new remote head 119134ce5d5d!
  (you should pull and merge or use push -f to force)
$ hg pull /media/USBNAME/docs
  pulling from /media/USBNAME/docs
  searching for changes
  adding changesets
  adding manifests
  adding file changes
  added 2 changesets with 0 changes to 0 files (+1 heads)
  (run 'hg heads' to see heads, 'hg merge' to merge)
$ hg merge
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 5 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
```

Above is what I just did and it looks just like my recollection of what happened the first time around. After the recommended pull and merge, 5 files were removed. Those are the files I want to push onto the USB, not remove. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your patience.

EDIT 2. re-focused my question by deleting distracting side questions.

SOLUTION. I now understand what the problem is in the second set of commands above: an hg update is missing in the destination repository. This is not obvious to the novice because while $hg pull throws a reminder to update, $hg push does not. Thus to properly push one needs to push from the source directory and then update from the destination directory.

Pulling gives a helpful reminder to update afterwards:

```
$ cd ~/dir-dest
$ hg pull ~/dir-source
  pulling from ~/dir-source
  searching for changes
  adding changesets
  adding manifests
  adding file changes
  added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
  (run 'hg update' to get a working copy)
$ hg update
```

Pushing gives no reminder to update and involves an additional step (one must cd to the destination):

```
$ cd ~/dir-source
$ hg push ~/dir-dest
  pushing to ~/dir-dest
  searching for changes
  adding changesets
  adding manifests
  adding file changes
  added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
$ cd ~/dir-dest
$ hg update
```

It would be convenient to have a push+udate command (pull+update already exists).

Once one knows what the problem is one can find references to it, but as far as I could tell there is no explicit example on how to use $hg push in https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Tutorial. (by contrast, $hg pull is well documented). And if I missed it, apologies.

Thanks to Martin who mentioned the importance of $hg update in one of his several comments below. His comment prompted me to experiment and to figure out what was missing in the sequence of steps I was following.

I imagine that my inability to push to the destination, which prompted my initial question, is a consequence of not having updated the destinaton repository at the propert time. The above is my understanding and will be edited if incorrect.

Comment: I've been able to do what I want by working from the USB
$ cd /media/USBNAME/docs
$ hg pull /home/docs
so how come I can pull but can't push?

Comment: I should be more precise, "how come I need to pull from the USB stick and can't push onto the USB stick?" and add "how come when I pull from the USB stick and merge my new files are removed?" During the merge process, how come I can't just choose to keep those files?

Comment: The files are deleted because they were deleted in the changesets you merge with and not touched in the changesets you currently have. This is considered a clear conflict-free situation by Mercurial: there's no conflicting modifications here.

Comment: thanks Martin, so what should I do to copy my new files onto the usb repository?

Comment: Please remember that this site isn't a discussion board. You should ask small and focussed questions about concrete problems you have. I suggest again that you start with a tutorial and really learn what multiple heads are and how merging works.

Comment: I apologize Martin for prolonging this discussion. Prompted by your remarks I have shortened my initial question --- still very much open, as far as I'm concerned. Perhaps someone will tell me how it is that I can't push new files to a clone and how it is that the clone will delete files in the original repo when I merge (if they are in a new directory, otherwise it works as expected). I haven't read anything about that in the documentation, so I'm still very much puzzled. Why do I need to pull from the clone, I don't get it. Thanks a lot anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try again and answer your two questions one by one:

## Pushing new files to a clone

> Perhaps someone will tell me how it is that I can't push new files to a clone?

There is a difference between `hg push` and `hg pull`. The two commands are mostly, but not completely, symmetric. The difference is that push will abort if it creates new heads in the remote repository. A *head* is a changeset without children. In this repository, `c` is the only head:

```
remote: [a] --- [b] --- [c]
```

Let us imagine you clone this and begin working. You create `x` and `y`:

```
local:  [a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [x] --- [y]
```

In parallel, someone creates `d` after `c` in the original (remote) repository:

```
remote: [a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [d]
```

Each repository now has **one head**, namely `y` in your repository and `d` in the remote.

If you try pushing, you'll be told:

```
$ hg push
pushing to /home/mg/tmp/remote
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote head a2f1cea74307!
(you should pull and merge or use push -f to force)
```

The "new remote head" is your `y` changeset. If it were pushed, you would have

```
remote: [a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [d]
                           \
                            [x] --- [y]
```

and so you see that there are **two heads** in the remote repository. This is normally a sign that someone has forgotten to pull and merge.

You should now pull and merge as suggested:

```
$ hg pull
pulling from /home/mg/tmp/remote
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files (+1 heads)
(run 'hg heads' to see heads, 'hg merge' to merge)
```

Your local repository will then get two heads (as seen by the `+1 heads`):

```
local:  [a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [x] --- [y]
                           \
                            [d]
```

This is normal and happens all the time when you pull. This is the **difference between push and pull**: pull will happily create multiple heads in your local repository, push will abort if it creates multiple heads in the remote repository.

You're now supposed to merge `d` into your `y` and commit. This creates:

```
local:  [a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [x] --- [y] --- [z]
                           \                   /
                            [d] --------------'
```

and you can now push `z` to the remote. Notice that when you push `z`, you're *not* creating multiple heads in the remote. I believe this is why you cannot push to your flash drive.

## Files deleted on merge

> how it is that the clone will delete files in the original repo when I merge

When you merge two heads, Mercurial looks at each file that was modified between the common ancestor point and the two heads. In the example above, it will look at files changed between `c` and `d` and files changed between `c` and `y`:

- If a file has been modified on both these paths, then Mercurial will try to do an internal three-way merge. If that fails, it starts a three-way merge tool (such as KDiff3) and ask you to resolve the conflicts.
- If a file has been modified on only one of the pats, then **this modifiction wins**.

Since the files are simply deleted from your working copy, then I conclude that the files were deleted in `d` and not touched in `x` or `y`. Check what files were changed with `hg status --change x` and `hg status --change y`.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation Martin. I'll have to read it again and experiment, but it's truly great to have. Before reading your second answer, I edited my question with a solution (hopefully, it's not too wrong). Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should read a [Mercurial tutorial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Tutorial) or [guide](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/basic/) to really learn the basics of `hg push` and `hg pull` and what [multiple heads mean](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MultipleHeads).

But yes, you can of course push and pull to a flash drive to keep your machines in sync. Focus on one repository (what you call a folder) and do

```
$ hg push /media/USB/folder
```

to send your changes to the flash drive. If it fails with "push creates new remote head", then that means that the flash drive has **some changes** than your current machine. You'll then want to pull and merge (as the error message hints). After the pull, the history looks like this in your repository:

```
[a] --- [b] --- [c]
           \
            [x] --- [y]
```

where `x` and `y` are the changesets you've just pulled. Your working copy still reflects changeset `c`. When you merge and commit, you integrate the latest changes from the flash drive (`x` and `y`) with the changes on your machine (`c`) into a new changeset `d`.

In the merge process, Mercurial first finds the common ancestor of `c` and `y`: `b`. It then looks at each file that was modified between `b` and `c`, and between `b` and `y`. If the file was only modified on one side of the merge, then that modification "wins" and becomes part of the merge. This includes deletions, so when fives files are deleted in your merge, then I can only conclude that they were deleted in either `x` or `y` above, and not touched in `c`. You can use `hg revert` to get them back before you commit the merge.

When the merge is committed you have:

```
[a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [d]
           \           /
            [x] --- [y]
```

You can then push back since you only have a **single head**, `d`. The commands are:

```
$ hg pull /media/USB/folder
$ hg merge
$ hg commit -m "Merge with latest stuff on machine X"
$ hg push /media/USB/folder
```

That's all basic Mercurial stuff and is covered in the tutorials. You write

> So I did a pull instead. But this deleted the new folders. I was able to get them back by doing `$ hg rollback; $ hg rervert newfolder/newfile`, but that was both scary and tedious.

Please don't run `hg rollback` for fun — never run it in the first months of using Mercurial :-) It's the only basic command that can cause data loss.

One point to focus on is that `hg pull` only transfers **history**. It doesn't touch the working copy directory at all. So it cannot have "deleted the new folders". Maybe you did `hg update tip` after the `hg pull`?

In any case, you should take a hard look at `hg log` and assure yourself that all the changesets are there, both new and old. See also `hg summary` and `hg heads` and maybe you'll find out that you have two heads. You have to `hg merge` them into one head so that you can continue working with one line of history.

Comment: Thanks Martin for this explanation. It will take me some time to process. I have read the tutorials you reference, but there are still basic things I don't understand. For instance, the repository in the USB was created with a clone command, then the repository in the computer was modified, then I tried to push: how could the USB have more changes? by your description, it would be impossible, so I must have done something strange without realizing. to be continued...

Comment: Not sure if I've got the language right here, but what I call a repository is a folder in which I did $hg init,etc. (and inside of which there is a .hg folder), while my "new folder" was created inside that repository, but it doesn't have an .hg folder inside, so I wasn't going to call that folder a repository, do I have this right?

Comment: thanks for the warning about rollback, I'll avoid that in the future, it just seemed like the only thing to do at the time. Let me follow the steps you describe and see if I get lucky this time around. Last time I never made it to the merge step because the pull command removed my new folders, but perhaps I did something wrong then, so I'll try again exactly as you describe and report back asap. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the link about multiple heads, now that's exactly the sort of tutorial that makes my head feel very multiple. I'm having problem with basic concepts like: heads, tips, tags, not to mention transplant extension. All those came in the first few paragraphs. I'm not even sure I understand changesets. If I understood what they are and do, I probably wouldn't have needed to post a question here  ;-)

Comment: just to illustrate my difficulty in processing information in those tutorials, consider this "First, the changesets to be merged are pulled from the source repository into the destination repository." To me, if you go from source to destination you "push", unless you first place yourself in the destination repository and "pull" from there (which is what I had to do with my USB, as I describe in my question), but wouldn't those two actions be equivalent? you pull from the left = you push from the right ...  [don't mind me, I'll go on reading]

Comment: "At that point, the original tip is still a head, but the tip of the source repository is also a head. Normally this case of multiple heads is only temporary, as the two heads are usually joined back into one right away, by performing a merge." This is going to kill me!

Comment: Martin, please refer to my first edit above, in reply to this "One point to focus on is that hg pull only transfers history. It doesn't touch the working copy directory at all. So it cannot have "deleted the new folders". Maybe you did hg update tip after the hg pull?"

Now the files were "removed" and I can't find them from within my file manager. Not sure if that's the same as deleted, but it sure is the same as gone   ;-)

Comment: Use `hg log --removed path/to/your-file` to see what has happened to this file. This works even if the file is not currently in your working copy. Also, familiarize yourself with `hg update` and see how the files change in the working copy.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll look into that. I didn't want to do $hg update since my beloved files had been removed. How about just forcing the push? I mean, is that a no-no? would it not push those files if I do $hg push -f  ?

Comment: Forcing the push wont destory anything — Mercurial is append-only, which means that `hg push` will only add things to the repository you push to. It will create two heads, though, and you'll want to `hg merge` and `hg commit` them. Use `hg revert` to re-surrect your file. I think I've already written this somewhere else though. So *please* go read up on the basic concepts and *try them out* in a test-repository.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that's probably the way to go for me, I'll experiment. I have been reading and testing Martin, I am highly educated and, believe me, I have tried hard, but the prose you send me to is quite foreign to me. If it weren't, as I said already, I wouldn't post questions here, I would just read the help files and take it from there, as I do with other software I use. I want to thank you for your help, you've been very kind.

Comment: Please come talk to us at http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=mercurial — that's our IRC channel and I'm `mg` there. There are lots of helpful people there that will be happy to guide you through the first steps with Mercurial. You're right that the terminology is strange at first — see `hg help glossary` if you haven't already — but you'll learn it after a while.